# Setting up an out-of-office automatic vacation response in Gmail

Tags: gmail

We use Gmail for official mail and we need to notify when someone is on vacation.

Where in the inbox settings do we set up an out-of-office, or vacation, responder that will send an email on our behalf during a specific time to incoming emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click on the gear icon at the top right of your inbox. It looks like this:

   > [image: gear icon in gmail]
2. Select **Settings**.
3. In the *General* tab, scroll down to "Vacation responder"
4. Select **Vacation responder on**
5. Fill out the dates you would like the response to be on and the subject and body for the message you would like to be sent as a reply.

   - Check the **Only send a response to people in my Contacts** if you don't want to send out the auto-responder to people not already in your address book.
6. Click **Save Changes**

Answer (score 4):

I'll pose the contrarian point of view -- I never, ever, ever set any of my e-mail accounts to out-of-office mode.  Why?  Two main reasons:

1. any spam coming into my account gets a prompt reply from the out-of-office responder, confirming to the spammer that this is a live, working address.  I really hate the thought of that.
2. I usually have e-mail access most places I go, and can browse for important stuff while I'm on the road.

Comment: Good point, although I don't remember the last time I received spam where the from address was an actual real live e-mail address.

Answer (score 2):

Click Settings and then scroll down to **Vacation responder**

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Settings" You should be in the "General" tab. Somewhere at the bottom there is a setting called "vacation responder". Just fill it out.