# Turning on Vacation Responder in Gmail

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up an out-of-office automatic vacation response in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/902/setting-up-an-out-of-office-automatic-vacation-response-in-gmail)

I can't find the word "settings" anywhere in my gmail account and want to turn on the vacation responder. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

With the new gmail interface, you need to go to the gear in the upper right corner of Gmail ... then click **Mail settings**.

Then, search for **Vacation responder**.

Hope this help
-CF-